# Why should we specify dependencies as we define a driver module in JBoss AS 7?

Tags: java, jboss, datasource

That's how is driver defined in the [official JBoss documentation](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7)

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">  
  <resources>  
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar"/>  
  </resources>  
  <dependencies>  
    <module name="javax.api"/>  
  </dependencies>  
</module
```

I didn't get why should we define the dependencies tag? What is it responsible for? Of course, We should define a path to a driver, it's clear. But the `<dependencies>` confused me. Could anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It states in the documentation link you've provided

> Finally, you define any dependencies you might have.  In this case, as the case with all JDBC data sources, we would be dependent on the Java JDBC API's, which in this case in defined in another module called javax.api, which you can find under **modules/javax/api/main** as you would expect.

You can look in the highlighted directory you'll find another `module.xml`. This is the module definition for the named module `"javax.api"`. Just as you have defined your module as `"com.mysql"`, if any other modules in the system needed your module, it would also define a `<dependencies>` element with your module name.

A module is simply defined as

> A Module is a logical grouping of classes used for class loading and dependency management...
>
> A module dependency is a declaration that one module requires the classes of another module in order to function. Modules can declare dependencies on any number of other modules. When the application server loads a module, the modular class loader parses the dependencies of that module and adds the classes from each dependency to its class path.

If you are familiar with Maven, it's kind of the same thing. A dependency may depend on other dependencies. In the `pom.xml` an artifact will define its dependencies. If you depend on that artifact, then you will also require *its* dependencies.

**Further Reading:**

- [Module Descriptors](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Module+descriptors)
- [Class Loadings and Modules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/chap-Class_Loading_and_Modules.html)